# What is the difference between the Lorentz force and the ponderomotive force?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, terminology, definition

I understand that Lorentz force is due to motion of moving charged particle in a magnetic field, and I imagine that ponderomotive force is mechanical version analogy to a person surfing on a wave super roughly speaking. I'm confused why the mass of the charged particle comes in?

I'm trying to prototype a battery operated portable LHC using laser to create a mega-tsunami of plasma or something like that in case you ask, all answers and comments in layman words please.

Comment: This question is discussed here: [What was meant by the 'ponderomotive force' as understood by Minkowski?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14295/)

Comment: @PeterDiehr It seems that the term "ponderomotive" has evolved since Minkowski's time, which is what the other question is about.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponderomotive_force

Comment: Mega-tsunami of plasma?

Comment: @KyleKanos: it is the powerful electric field produced in its wake that should catch your attention, not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In layman terms the Lorenz force is a first order equation in velocity. The charged particle has a constant v for the standard formula that gives [the Lorenz force.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force#Lorentz_force_in_terms_of_potentials)

[image: lorenzforce]

In nature and in the lab there exist nonlinear situations, where v is not a constant but changes. This has been studied and the second order solution  for the motion of a particle in an electromagnetic potential A comes from a force which  has been given the name of "ponderomotive force".

[image: ponderomotiveforce]

This  definition is useful in laser plasma set ups, and for particle acceleration with lasers. See [the link for details](https://www.kth.se/polopoly_fs/1.254029!/Menu/general/column-content/attachment/report07.pdf) of derivation.

The mass enters because of the mathematics of the Maxwell's equations for the problem: charged particle in an inhomogeneous fields.

Comment: The ponderomotive force or rather the associated potential plays an important role in multi-photon ionisation in strong laser fields. This potential, a spatially localised $A^2$ term in the Hamiltonian which is non-negative acts as a finite barrier leading to a tunnel effect mechanism which effectively suppresses a number of multi-photon ionisation channels. It hyas been confirmed experimentally.